# How can I rewrite password hasher written on Lua with Python?

Tags: python, authentication, encryption, hash, lua

I have to rewrite password hasher for my Django app could work with legacy database (old hasher written on Lua). I made almost exactly the same code, but it returns another hash.

This is my code:

```
def encode(password, salt):

    first_pass = hashlib.sha512()
    salted = (password + salt).encode('utf-8')

    first_pass.update(salted)

    digest = first_pass.digest()

    for i in range(1, 5000):
        next_pass = hashlib.sha512()
        next_pass.update(digest + salted)
        digest = next_pass.digest()

    hash = base64.b64encode(digest).decode('utf-8').strip()
    return hash
```

This is the code in Lua:

```
function M.password_to_hash(plain_password, salt)

    local resty_sha512 = require("resty.sha512")

    local salted = plain_password.."{"..salt.."}"
    local first_pass = resty_sha512:new()

    first_pass:update(salted)

    local digest = first_pass:final()

    for i = 1, 4999 do
        local next_pass = resty_sha512:new()
        next_pass:update(digest..salted)
        digest = next_pass:final()
    end

    return ngx.encode_base64(digest)
end
```

I need these fragments to return equal hashes.

Example:

```
password = testdevel

salt = 9675zt3fmtc0kg0c08k4c8wosc0ss8s
```

Python function returns:

```
6UbnltvNR6Y+wnUe2pd7RW/XglSB0SczKr7bUFCmv5l58eXuV2j3b9aSsD4DBeG44M6eJhStYE1sQIa95XbzlQ==
```

Lua function returns:

```
d5/dFCOfKDppXs5EYe3fGL+TF/0QN9myHTqXn0Ml8Xp7+bUOOTp2xuHjjm91mQNCxMJHiWleZtGRU86OqR5s9g==
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output from the two functions

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with lua, but it looks like your lua function sets `salted` to `<password>{<salt>}`, while your Python function sets `salted` to `<password><salt>`.  You would expect these to generate different hashes because you're providing different input to the hash function.

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`salted` in python should be:

```
salted = (password + '{' + salt + '}').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: In Lua You are actually concatenating `salted` as this:
`plain_password.."{"..salt.."}"`
Which basically will give you `"plain_password{salt}`" and in Python You have omitted this brackets so You will basically have `"plain_passwordsalt"`, this will end up in totally different hash.